# ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS only turn on GPS but permission is still not granted in Android 10

Tags: android

My app needs location, it works well in Android 9. But in Android 10, the `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` doesn't grant the permission, only turn on the GPS.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void goToSettings() {
    Intent myAppSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(myAppSettings);
}
```

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

If I tried to use `startActivityForResult`, no matter what action the user does, it always returns `RESULT_CANCELED`

Answer (score 0):

[https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes]

> Android 10 introduces the
> ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.
>
> Unlike the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> permissions, the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission only affects an
> app's access to location when it runs in the background. An app is
> considered to be accessing location in the background unless one of
> the following conditions is satisfied:
>
> An activity belonging to the app is visible. The app is running a
> foreground service that has declared a foreground service type of
> location.

Perhaps you need to request the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission.

Also, I found this in the documentation

> ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS
>
> Activity Action: Show settings to allow configuration of security and location privacy.

Which might be the activity you need.

Comment: I never ask for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` anywhere in the whole project.

Comment: `ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS` goes to Privacy Settings not Location Settings.

Comment: I tried to the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` in the manifest, but still got the same thing. It seems, in Android 10, once the user denied, then the only way is, the users themselves must manually go to `Settings` and grant it by themselves.

Comment: You could let the user know that in a toast and end the activity to get the point across.